# Outlook 2010: How do I configure Outlook to not mark messages as read on (IMAP) server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

Microsoft Outlook 2010: Right now our company shares a staff email via IMAP. Kind of cheap until we get our exchange server running...

The problem is, if one person sees the email, it is marked read for everyone else. How do I make it so it is only marked as read *locally* and not on the server (for everyone else).

Answer (score 1):

The IMAP system works by always showing you what is on the server, there is no local copy (apart from what is cached). Flags such as Read/Unread, etc. are also stored with each email on the server so everybody sees the same thing.

However one thing you could do is train everybody up so they only use the Reading Pane to view the messages and then set the Reading pane options (Options/Mail/Outlook panes/Reading pane...) so the item is never marked as read when viewed there.

If anyone opens the email in a separate Window it will still be marked as read but they could also mark it as unread again.

Answer (score 0):

Could you set the accounts up as POP - leave a copy on the server? This would usually achieve the desired effect

You could set this to delete if deleted also...

Answer (score -1):

These instructions are for Outlook 2007 so hopefully they haven't changed it too much:

1. In Outlook, click **Tools** > **Account Settings...**
2. Make sure the account you want to modify is selected and click **Change...**
3. Click the **More Settings...** button
4. On the **Advanced** tab, check **Leave a copy of message on the server**
5. Click **OK**, **Next**, **Finish**, and **Close**

Comment: This should only work for POP3 e-mail, not IMAP. IMAP always leaves a copy on the server.